# Does magento-1 tag make any sense?

Tags: discussion, tags

Does `magento-1` tag make any sense? Would it be better to use `ce-x.x.x.x` and `ee-x.x.x.x` instead? This can avoid further clarification requests.

Comment: How the heck could it be that you ask a very similar question to mine http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65/how-should-we-manage-magento-versions/66#66 one hour before me?

Comment: great minds think alike :-)

Comment: Hi Robert. It's ok that the question was closed, but how it can be a duplicate if it was asked before the other one?

Comment: My question was better ;-) And it already had an answer. Which was actually yours ;-) Bad luck, buddy ;-)

Comment: I don't mind as long as we use full Magento version as a tag :-)