# Magento version tag spamming / General "Magento 1" questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I am recently seeing an increased amount of questions tagged like [magento-1.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.7), [magento-1.8](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.8), [magento-1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9). (**all of them!**)

**These questions fall into two categories:**

1. Questions that specify the actually used version in the question body ("I am using Magento 1.9")
2. General questions that are looking for answers valid for all common Magento 1 versions.

**How should we deal with those tags?**

I find (2) a valid reason as long as the existing [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) tag is still discouraged (See [Does magento-1 tag make any sense?](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64/does-magento-1-tag-make-any-sense)). Not adding a version tag at all will soon be a problem with increasing number of Magento 2 questions.

In case of (1) it looks like an attempt to gain more visibility by tag spamming. Since the maximum number of tags per question is 5, I don't know if it really has impact in this sense, but it devalues the meaning of these tags.

Comment: I found that the the 'magento-1.x' tags are sometimes the only tag and only hint to the OPs questions as they do not mention it in the text.

Answer (score 5):

This has been mentioned before and a big portion of edits in the origination of this SE site was to move the mention of the Magento version to the tag.

I prefer this, honestly, because it cuts down on the visual noise of the question itself.

As far as tagging with a `Magento-1` tag, I prefer this as well because it will have historical value. **There should be no need** to have both a `Magento-1` **AND** a `Magento-1.7` tag.

Comment: So far, so good. But what about questions with multiple version tags? Maybe that wasn't stated clear enough in my question

Comment: Please see my edit.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure there's a clear answer, so this is a good thing to discuss & decide as a community. In general, we may need to decide on a case-by-case basis. Here are my thoughts in no particular order:

- When a question clearly speaks to multiple versions, this should be allowed.
- For general M1 questions, the [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) seems appropriate, though TBH I'd assume these are rare, and it would be ideal to know the specific version in use.
- Mass edits related to version tagging should be evaluated as spam, unless its clear that it's in the pursuit of better curation.
- As Phil said, [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) is probably not appropriate to use when a more granular & necessarily inclusive tag (e.g. [magento-1.7](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.7) is present.

Comment: 1. Agreed, however this is really rare, with the exception of upgrade related questions, where it makes perfect sense to tag old and new version; 2. I don't think they are that rare. Think about questions about understanding general concepts or practices, questions that did not need a version tag until Magento 2 got relevant; 3. If you mean adding arbitrary tags to old questions, I agree. Everything else would be in pursuit of better curation, right? 4. Agreed, the `magento-1` tag is redundant if a more specific tag is used

Answer (score 1):

If they have multiple 1.x versions inside the tags, I am for keeping the newest version, and removing the others.
Maybe also keep the lowest, when the question may include Backwards compatibility.

For example some people may ignore questions, which dont target at least 1.8, while others have more experience with problems regarding older versions.