# Usage of the magento-1 tag if no version is specified in question

Tags: discussion, tags

Since Magento 2 is out a great number of new questions is about Magento 2 and we need a way to distinguish general Magento 1 questions from general Magento 2 questions (as already discussed in [Magento version tag spamming / General "Magento 1" questions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/687/magento-version-tag-spamming-general-magento-1-questions)).

Almost all Magento 2 questions use the [magento-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-2) tag and I started adding the [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) tag to questions that don't target a specific Magento 1 version or where it was not specified, so that they can be at least distinguished from Magento 2 questions, which at some point will probably be the majority here.

Now today this resulted in kind of an edit war:

[image: tag edit war]

Somebody (not the OP) thought, [magento-1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) would be more appropiate, although the version was not mentioned in question or comments. Next, the tag was removed (probably for this reason) but without rolling back to the version with [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1).

Before this gets out of hand, I'd like to get some opinions again: Is it useful to add [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) to questions that are obviously about Magento 1, but without specifying the minor version? Or should it better be left without version tag until it has been clarified by the OP? Always assuming [magento-1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) is obviously not a good idea.

Comment: I've also seen this and these edits and they are always commented as "These tags may help to find the solution for this question." while there is nowhere said (by the OP) that the version is 1.9. Maybe this user want's to gain rep with tag spam edits? So you've probably started this post based on one incident...?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that more specific tags are better in the long run than less specific. For instance:

- Where not specified by the poster, but is obviously M1, we can apply `magento-1`
- Where not specified by the OP, but is obviously M2, we can apply `magento-2`
- Where it IS specified, but is not tagged, we can apply either tag as we see fit.

I will always prefer a Magento-1.9 tag to a Magento-1 tag.

Comment: ACK, that's how I handle it as well.

Comment: Accepted because it's a simple rule that makes sense and is easy to remember. Also it seems to be consent to prefer more specific version tags over less specific ones. If I could accept two answers, the one by @hakre would be the second, as it points out that there is no *need* to retag old questions.

Comment: @philwinkle, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161213/change-the-default-value-of-is-active-for-customer-in-magneto-2?noredirect=1#comment241400_161213

Answer (score 8):

Most new-to-Magento developers will be jumping into 2.x. Given the sheer amount of content to learn, I can see the use for dichotomous tagging as a way for developers to quickly recognize whether a question does or does not apply their issue (or to filter these in the first place).

Answer (score 4):

I think that *new* questions (they all have a date) will be tagged [magento-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-2) when it's about the new version.

Older questions (I can only repeat it, all questions have a date) won't get touched only because there is a new version. I'd say that is totally fine. So I don't see any *need* to tag old questions with [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) (168) or [magento-1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) (6,648) or [legacy](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/legacy) (0) or [global-static-hell](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/global-static-hell) (0) or what not just because magento two is out.

Keep in mind that next to the date of a post, there is also the last modified date. Changing tags on old questions will warm them up - something you most likely do not want to have them better distinguished for this version transition.

New questions explicitly about magento one will actually need to make themselves distinguishable from magento 2 and in context of these, it might be useful to tag them with a concrete version if the OP thinks so - and most often she will do so today already. So nothing to explicitly take care of next to the normal editing duties.

Apart from that you will see in some time that again the [magento-2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-2) will proof itself not being helpful and then there will be more need to distinguish between the community and the enterprise release for example. Magento one will vanish more and more by that time.

So leave them as is. Don't take part in edit wars. Most often the tag is too much of a detail to properly work when it comes to dissent. Really check the question if the version of magento is the important part or if it's more about the database layer for example.

Comment: You make good points here. Just to clarify, I did not intend mass editing old posts, atm I add the tag when I'm about to edit such questions anyway which brings them to the top.

Comment: I think that's fine. However, for old questions you can normally assume that they are related to the legacy version of magento I'd say.

Comment: Some day the exact release date will be forgotten ;)

Answer (score 3):

Adding the [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) tag sounds great. Specially for questions that aren't too obvious.

If anyone can add a more specific version tag it should only be done when it's absolutely clear. Otherwise it has little use. Ran into the same issue as well and I think it should be discouraged.

Answer (score 3):

i am not in favor of using the tag `magento-1` because this tag cannot sum up  these tag `magento1.7,magent-1.8,magento-1.9` questions and  i agree with @philwinkle answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in favor of `magento-1.x` tag rather than `magento-1.  It helps concrete the idea that it's on the Magento 1 platform but that the version has not been specified.

Comment: That would require a tag rename or synonym but I'm fine with it as long as Magento2 is renamed to magento-2.x for consistency

Comment: I completely agree

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/161213/change-the-default-value-of-is-active-for-customer-in-magneto-2?noredirect=1#comment241400_161213