# Reviewers: Please do not approve irrelevant version tags

Tags: discussion, tags

At least [one user](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/38476/nits?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) is currently suggesting to add the [magento-1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) tag to many questions, some of them even older than Magento 1.9.

**Please don't blindly accept those!** Adding missing version tags makes sense, but it's useless if there is no indication in the question or comments on a specific version.

*Note that you don't see comments in the review queue. I always open the question in a new tab to see if the suggested edit is the result of a clarifying comment*

If there is code involved, you will probably recognize [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) or [magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento2) - then feel free to add these tags. But don't assume 1.9 or 2.1 or whatever. See also: [Usage of the magento-1 tag if no version is specified in question](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/778/usage-of-the-magento-1-tag-if-no-version-is-specified-in-question)

If there is no code involved, some questions can even be answered completeley independent of the version. **Not every question needs a version tag**.

If the version is unclear from the question but important to answer it, add a comment to ask for the version, instead of adding a tag that might be wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: I can barely resist the urge to retag this with `magento-1.9`. All joking aside, you are 100% right. Version tags should be added only if it's really obvious from the question that the problem is for that specific version.

Comment: Similar question I asked a few months ago: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/921/what-can-i-do-to-avoid-such-behavior

Comment: Ah, I remember. I had to bring up the topic again in hope that the right people see it.

Comment: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/500/quality-of-review-process